# Draw a rectangle with an arc cut on one side

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm beginning to start to draw custom shapes using core graphics on iOS. Right now I am trying to draw a rectangle with a transparent arc cut on one side.

[image]

I'm trying to use the `CGContextAddArcToPoint` function to draw the arc but can't get the gist out of it. Also, is there other way to achieve this shape?

Comment: first draw a rectangle with fill color red. then over that draw a circle with fill the color white.

Comment: @VineeshTP, forgot to mention that it should be transparent. :)

Comment: if it is transparent then , what color surrounding this ?

Comment: @VineeshTP, it can be color and there is no way of knowing it, thus, the arc portion should be transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Set fill color to red
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

// Move to the upper-left corner of the rect
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));

// Add a line to the left side of the hole
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect) - holeRadius, CGRectGetMinY(rect));

// Add the semi-circular hole
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect), holeRadius, M_PI, 0, 1);

// Add a line to the top-right corner
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));

// Add the remaining sides of the rectangle
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

// Close path and fill with current fill color
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

[image: Resulting image]

Now, the really fun part is figuring out how to make it an elliptical hole instead of a circular one. That I leave to the reader :)

Comment: thanks @warrenm, will start on this to achieve an elliptical hole just like the sample image on my post. :)

Comment: Hint: with suitably chosen control points, you can get any hole shape you want with one or more calls to `CGContextAddCurveToPoint`. There is no function that draws a portion of an ellipse.